# javascript query selector issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select nested h2 tag by queryselector in javascript, but this seems like not working, I do not see any result on page.

```
var changeTextForBundle = document.querySelector('.picky-bundler-container .picky-custom-html h2');      
      changeTextForBundle.style.background-color:='#363636';
```

HTML File

```
<div data-v-3efab0bc="" class="picky-bundler-container picky-widget">
    <div data-v-3c43f93f="" data-v-3efab0bc="" class="picky-custom-html">
        <h2 style="width:100%; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">Frequently Bought Together</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also want to change the text of h2 tag, but this 
changeTextForBundle.innerHTML = 'AAA';
is also not working

Comment: Can you add an HTML file also for better understanding ?

Comment: Please check your browser's console. for error messages.

Comment: html
<div data-v-3efab0bc="" class="picky-bundler-container picky-widget"><div data-v-3c43f93f="" data-v-3efab0bc="" class="picky-custom-html"><h2 style="width:100%; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">Frequently Bought Together</h2></div>
</div>

Comment: @FrontendDevWebAccessibility I know you have some answers done there and without seeing the source code of this site because it seems that you probably using external style sheets. With this being a possibility, you may have to use the `!important` modifier to override another CSS rule that is being applied to the element.

Answer (score 2):

You're using strange syntax.

```
var changeTextForBundle = document.querySelector('.picky-bundler-container .picky-custom-html h2');
changeTextForBundle.style.backgroundColor='#363636';
```

should work better ;)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Comment: of course you have to keep the selection. I edit my message

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if you have a problem with the CSS selector in `querySelector`, but you may want to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all element matching the selectors.

What doesn't look right is trying to set the `background-color` in your JavaScript code. [Change the `background-color` setting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) in JavaScript with `backgroundColor`:

```js
var changeTextForBundle = document.querySelector('.picky-bundler-container .picky-custom-html h2');      
changeTextForBundle.style.backgroundColor = '#363636';
```

If you would like to use the `querySelectorAll` option, the following code would perform the same task for all elements matching your selector string:

```js
var changeTextForBundle = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".picky-bundler-container .picky-custom-html h2"
);
changeTextForBundle.forEach(function (element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "#363636";
});
```

#### Runnable example

```js
var changeTextForBundle = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".picky-bundler-container .picky-custom-html h2"
);
changeTextForBundle.forEach(function(element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "#363636";
});
```

```html
<div class="picky-bundler-container picky-widget">
  <div class="picky-custom-html">
    <h2 style="width:100%; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">Frequently Bought Together</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```